# how to fix Blank graphs when using figure module in PyDev?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I have a problem when making graphs using matplotlib,
for some simple graphs the library works fine, for example:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
    plt.ylabel('some numbers')
    plt.show()
```

but when I use *figure* module, i get blank figures, like this

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
    y = np.sin(x)
    ax.plot(x, y, 'r-', linewidth=2, label=r'$y=\sin(x)$', alpha=0.6)
    ax.legend(loc='upper center')
    plt.show()
```

I've tried the same code in a a different python editor or using the shell and it woks fine. I'm using :
Windows,
PyDev v4.2, 
python v2.7.10